# iphone xcode; releasing a view instance crashing the table with datasource

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My code crashes with a bad access, when i have a view with tables. I have figured what the problem is, but looking for the right solution.

In View 1 - i have a button that creates and instance of view 2 and then releases it, something like this:

```
  settingsScreen *settings = [[settingsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsScreen" bundle:nil];
  CGRect theFrame = settings.view.frame;
  //theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
  theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,-(self.view.frame.size.height));
  settings.view.frame = theFrame;
  theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8f];
  settings.view.frame = theFrame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
  [self.view addSubview:settings.view];
  [settings release];
```

In view 2 there is table, where i am setting the datasource and delegate to self on viewDidLoad, but this crashes the app with exec_bad_access

If i remove [settings release] in View 1, everything is fine.

If i do not release the view, is'nt it wrong to leave it in the memory?

how can i get over this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use either pushViewController or presentModalViewController instead of adding a view of one Viewcontroller in another Viewcontroller and when you want to come back you can use popViewController or dismissModalViewController, this helps in memory management as well. Also use [NSBundle mainBundle] for bundle parameter in initWithNibName which finds proper xib in the bundle.

I am sure somehow your settings instance is being released somewhere in your code again and it makes your app unstable.

Comment: if i use autorelease, i still run into similar problems. Sorry for the lame question, if i want to use presentModalView controller, without a navigation controller, what's the hierarchy? window -> View Controller -> View? any example that i can be pointed to?

Comment: You can call presentModalViewController using viewControllers instance also.

Comment: e.g UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyviewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];     [self presentModalViewController:viewController1 animated:YES]; [viewController1 release]; // you just need to understand viewcontroller concept, they maintain one view attached to them, like their events, memory consumption, data,etc. if you add views to different view controller then program won't be stable, you won't get proper events at desired location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works, but wondering, if i show a view controller using presentModalViewController, what happens to the previous view? cause i am not able to access any of its outlets when i dismiss the viwe and get back to it - i posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226040/xcode-iphone-understanding-the-view-controller-presentmodalviewcontroller . can someone guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sanniv's answer is correct. You should use push-pop concept of [navigation controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) or present the controller in a modal way.
(Visit: i) http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=472236 & ii) http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3643-pushviewcontroller-versus-presentmodalviewcontroller.html for more info).

Now the error you're getting is because of your "settings" object is being used in animation which you're releasing before your animation gets finished. Thus, instead of releasing the object immediately, release in another method which would be called exactly after animation stops. Like following way:

```
settingsScreen *settings = [[settingsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsScreen" bundle:nil];
CGRect theFrame = settings.view.frame;
//theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,-(self.view.frame.size.height));
settings.view.frame = theFrame;
theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8f];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(releaseObjects)];

settings.view.frame = theFrame;
[self.view addSubview:settings.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In the "releaseObjects" objects method, you should release your settings object. And in a case, if your settings object is a local, do it autorelease like this way -

```
settingsScreen *settings = [[[settingsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```